# Do I need to "import React" if I use JSX syntax?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I created a React app via Create React App. In the `App.js` file, there is no `import React from 'react';`, though it works correctly when I run it. Then I set up ESLint like this:

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "react-app"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error"
    },
    "plugins": ["prettier"]
}
```

After that the app doesn't run with an error:

```
React' must be in scope when using JSX        react/react-in-jsx-scope
```

What is the more correct way to fix that - to add an exception to the ESLint rules or to explicitly import React wherever I use JSX?

Comment: React 17 provides [a different way](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#new-jsx-transform) to transform JSX that means `React` doesn't have to be in scope. If you're using that, you can disable the rule.

Comment: Thank you, @jonrsharpe 
Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From React 17* there is a [new JSX transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) that no longer requires an explicit `import React from "react";`. If you're using this transform, you no longer need that ESLint rule enabled; this is explicitly called out in the post:

> #### ESLint
>
> If you are using
> [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react),
> the `react/jsx-uses-react` and `react/react-in-jsx-scope` rules are no
> longer necessary and can be turned off or removed.
>
> ```json
> {
>   // ...
>   "rules": {
>     // ...
>     "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
>     "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
>   }
> }
> ```

* *and v16.14.0, v15.7.0, v0.14.10*